# cannot create directory at db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have repository at github for ruby on rails project. 
First time i did push from comp. under windows system with msysgit. 
Then cloned this project from another comp. under ubuntu, did some changes, commited and pushed to repository at github.
Now when i try to pull or even clone this repository from my comp. with windwos it results in error:

```
fatal: cannot create directory at db:migrate
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? And what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: why does git complain about db:migrate, which is a rake task and not a file on the filesystem. Maybe you accidentally created this file and are now trying to create it on the file system? I think "db:migrate" isn't a valid name for a directory.

Comment: True. I looked at files and dirs of my project and saw db:migrate directory that was created when i misstyped "rails" instead of "rake" when did migrations. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You would not be out of disk space?
This is the usual reason for that kind of error message.

Other reason: a directory with a non-Windows naming convention (like [this thread](http://mail.flashcodersny.org/pipermail/flashcodersny_flashcodersny.org/2009-March/011003.html), where a directory contains an extra space at the end of its name)

Answer (score 0):

It also may be a weird permissions error.